# Difference between pandas Series category data type vs pandas Categorical data type

Tags: python, pandas

I'm coming up against this surprising inability to access what I expected to have a `codes` attribute for a column of data in a CSV that I'm coercing to a category type via the `dtype` parameter to `read_csv`.

If I run the following code

```
import pandas

csv_str = """c1,c2
a,1
b,2
a,3
c,4
a,5"""

df = pandas.read_csv( pandas.compat.StringIO( csv_str ) , dtype={'c1':'category'} )

print( "DataFrame\n{}".format( df ))
print( "\nDataTypes\n{}".format( df.dtypes ))
print( "\nDataCodes\n{}".format( pandas.Categorical( df['c1'] ).codes ))

# EXCEPTION
print( df['c1'].codes )
```

I get the following console output

```
DataFrame
  c1  c2
0  a   1
1  b   2
2  a   3
3  c   4
4  a   5

DataTypes
c1    category
c2       int64
dtype: object

DataCodes
[0 1 0 2 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/$USER/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print( df['c1'].codes )
  File "/Users/$USER/Applications_User/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'codes'
```

What's going on here exactly, why can't I treat my c1 column that is a category type as Categorical? I think I'm missing some subtle point here. What is the difference between pandas category valued Series vs a pandas Categorical data type.

Is there an alternate route to accessing the category valued series' codes directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.Categorical` returns an object of `Categorical` type:

```
c = pd.Categorical(df['c1'])
c
# [a, b, a, c, a]
# Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]

type(c)
pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical
```

OTOH, `df['c1']` is a `Series` of type `categorical`. This means that its categorical attributes and functions must be accessed through the [`.cat` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.html).

```
type(df['c1'])
# pandas.core.series.Series

df['c1'].cat.codes

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    0
dtype: int8
```

Comment: beautiful, not to be confused with `pandas.Series.str.cat` either.